# Need to know the right way to scan infected website files

Tags: wordpress, hosting

My website index.php and htaccess. file got infected and another PHP file of plugin and the website is down now. See the snapshot in this link [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6wLmLAtHwZCZnhmV0QzdDMyTW8][1]

could you tell my the way to scan these files? I have scanned with some free antivirus but it is not showing any virus infection. Help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your admin panel is accessible, try adding [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/)! It will scan all the files for malware and provide you the full scan report.

Hope this will help!

Comment: No, i cannot access the WordPress admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Clamav](https://www.clamav.net/downloads) antivirus scanner which can be done via command line.

Download and install it via command line tools. Document for clamav : https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav

Comment: i have tried installing that. But when i open the freshclam.exe through cmd. i getting the `error as "file cannot be opened". shall i use ClamWin rather than ClamAV

Comment: Yes you can use that also : ClamWin

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove .htacess and index.php file both are default so you can reupload the code from google. Also you can scan your website with maldet scanner.

Comment: "Please try to remove .htacess and index.php file both are default so you can reupload the code from google".I do not get this. Do you mean that both the files are same for all the WordPress websites? so, i can get those two files by googling. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, both files are same/default for WordPress.